# can i mine any cryptocurrency in my pc

Tags: gpu-mining, cpu-mining

i need help to see that if my pc can mine any cryptocurrency.

my spces:

Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

i3 2100 3.10GHz

AMD Radeon HD 6450

3gb Ram

If anyone needs more info about my pc they can tell me about what they want to know.

Answer (score 0):

you can mine, I think you should look over to some places where you could mine.

- probably one of the most popular would be [Nicehash](https://www.nicehash.com/).

*There are several calculators on the internet, also a [nicehash calc](https://www.nicehash.com/?p=calc) which you could use.*

Beside nicehash, there is a ton of renting pages and mining pages. Check them out to find what you are looking for. I also like https://www.miningrigrentals.com/ (*when I was mining, I dont anymore*).

Comment: but after downloading the nicehash miner in the device column it is not showing anything

Comment: Please read their [_Getting Started_](https://www.nicehash.com/?p=gstarted). Everything is explained there very well, including which software and how to use it.